# Nest JS doesn't have permissions to copy GRPC files inside docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I have a docker container running via docker-compose with the command as running nestjs in dev mode:

```
FROM node:16-alpine as base
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat tini

FROM base as dev

ENV NODE_ENV development
USER node
WORKDIR /home/node
# copy all files over
COPY --chown=node:node ./ ./

RUN mkdir -p ./my-app/dist/shared/grpc
RUN chown -R node:node ./my-app/dist
RUN chown -R node:node ./my-app/dist/shared/grpc
```

My grpc files are in a shared project. the full structure is:

```
services/shared
services/my-app
```

The shared project has grpc files inside the directory `shared/grpc`.

NestJS copies these over to it's dist folder when building. As this is dev, that's every code change or on docker error:

my-app/nest-cli.json:

```
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "assets": [
      {
        "include": "../../shared/grpc/*.proto",
        "outDir": "./dist/shared/grpc"
      }
    ],
    "watchAssets": true
  },
  "entryFile": "/my-app/src/main"
}
```

NestJS seems to detect 0 errors, but fails on the copying of the grpc files:

```
my-app_1           | [7:06:11 AM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
my-app_1           | 
my-app_1           | node:fs:1828
my-app_1           |   handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
my-app_1           |   ^
my-app_1           | 
my-app_1           | Error [ShellJSInternalError]: EPERM: operation not permitted, chmod 'dist/shared/grpc/apps.proto'
my-app_1           |     at Object.chmodSync (node:fs:1828:3)
my-app_1           |     at copyFileSync (/home/node/my-app/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:78:8)
my-app_1           |     at /home/node/my-app/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:298:7
my-app_1           |     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
my-app_1           |     at Object._cp (/home/node/my-app/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:243:11)
my-app_1           |     at Object.cp (/home/node/my-app/node_modules/shelljs/src/common.js:384:25)
my-app_1           |     at AssetsManager.actionOnFile (/home/node/my-app/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/lib/compiler/assets-manager.js:95:19)
my-app_1           |     at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/node/my-app/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/lib/compiler/assets-manager.js:70:47)
my-app_1           |     at FSWatcher.emit (node:events:520:28)
my-app_1           |     at FSWatcher.emitWithAll (/home/node/my-app/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:540:8) {
my-app_1           |   errno: -1,
my-app_1           |   syscall: 'chmod',
my-app_1           |   code: 'EPERM',
my-app_1           |   path: 'dist/shared/grpc/apps.proto'
my-app_1           | }
my-app_1           | error Command failed with exit code 1.
my-app_1           | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
my-app_1           | yarn run v1.22.17
```

However I can't work out why - it has ownership of all the folders it needs to access. Here's my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  my-app:
    build:
      context: .
      target: dev
      dockerfile: ./my-app/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    user: node
    ports:
        - 3003:3000
    volumes:
      - ./my-app:/home/node/my-app
      - ./shared:/home/node/shared
    working_dir: /home/node/my-app
    command: yarn run start:dev

volumes:
  my-app:
```

Edit 1

After removing `USER node` from Dockerfile and docker-compose this works. But that means node is running as root which is not OK and not a secure solution. I have even tried adding `RUN chmod -R 777 /home/node` within Dockerfile and that doesnt work. There must be something behind the scenes in nestjs that needs specific permissions but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party, but it was my `nest-cli.json` file that was causing the issue for me.

under `compilerOptions` I listed assets that aren't normally watched by Nest (ie: `.proto` or in my case `.ejs` files). Removing that line fixed it for me, so it had to do with me running the app in `--watch` mode and it needing to hot reload that file and not having permissions to copy it.

nest-cli.json:

```
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "assets": [
      "app/**/**/*.ejs"
    ],
    "watchAssets": true
  }
}
```